# My Play app is very slow

Tags: playframework

I'm a begginer with PlayFramework and I have a few questions about how to put the server to work properly.

I have been reading a few tutorials on how to deploy a Play! app and I decided to use the server that comes with it and lighttpd as reverse proxy. (I want to deploy 2 or 3 apps in the same machine with different domain)

My app is just like a youtube with only two pages, list videos and upload video. Nothing else is done with the app. I use mysql server for the database.

The machine is a VPS with 1024 RAM with Debian, it does not have swap partition.

The URL to the app is [proselo.info](http://proselo.info) and it is quite slow.

---

I've made a test with ab and you can see the results below:

ab -n 150 http://proselo.info/listar

Total transferred: 185250 bytes

HTML transferred:       124800 bytes

Requests per second:    2.01 [#/sec] (mean)

Time per request:       498.539 [ms] (mean)

Time per request:       498.539 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)

Transfer rate:          2.42 [Kbytes/sec] received

---

Any help will be apreciated

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to do a bit more investigation. Is it actually your application which is slow? If so you probably need to time your ins and outs of different modules component. Databases are often the main bottlenecks. also are you running you app in Prod more?

Comment: how far away is the server from you? does anything else run fast? (i.e. how fast is it to just run `ab` for lighthttp). maybe it's a dirt cheap network your vps is on? maybe try running traceroute and post the results ...

Answer (score 3):

It's been long time since I posted this question but the problem was that I really did not put it in production mode.

Sorry for the inconvenience, now i0ts much better!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look slow when loading from my browser. What else do you have running on your VPS? It may be that you are hitting some limit in your VPS when doing the test (cpu, ram) and that's the reason of the delays.

Comment: There is nothing else than lighttpd anf the play server load average: 0.02, 0.07, 0.06                                     Mem:   1048576k total,   608056k used,   440520k free  I will make some more test to see if anything changes. Thanks!

Comment: I tired again an it runs fast... maybe some lighttpd config issue? Play in Dev mode? Having only 1 thread enabled in Play?